# Deciding Intuitionistic Logic via QBF

Tags: complexity-theory, logic

I want an algorithm to decide whether a theorem holds in propositional Intuitionistic logic ($IL$). We know $IL$ is $PSPACE$-complete, so we should be able to reduce $IL$ to $QBF$.

In Literature i only found reductions the other way around, so im assuming this is not  the way to go for writing an algorithm deciding $IL$. Am i right about this?

Another way would be to use the Gödel-McKinsey translation into $S4$ and using a $CTL^*$ solver, but im trying to keep it simple.

My question is, is there an easy (not necessarily fast) way to decide $IL$? Can the reduction to $QBF$ still work?

Comment: It would appear that [the standard proof](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397579900069) of the PSPACE upper bound in the literature is indeed to reduce intuitionistic logic to S4 and then use the method from Ladner (1977). "[The computational complexity of provability in systems of modal propositional logic](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.705.4317)."

Comment: There are lots of other hits you can find by searching _intuitionistic propositional logic decision procedures_. I don't know whether any of them qualify as "easy" for whatever definition you are looking for, though.